# Corrent means of coding a directive in Angular

Tags: angularjs, directive

I have some code here

```
<div ng-repeat="student in students" class="student">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="row placeholder">
                <img data-src="holder.js/200x200/auto/sky" class="img-responsive profile" alt="200x200" src="#" data-holder-rendered="true">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10" style="padding: 17px 40px;">
            <div class="row"><h1 class="name"><a href="/database/profile.php?id=2015552117"><span>{{ student.FirstName }}</span> {{ student.LastName }} , {{ student.MiddleName }}</a></h1></div>
            <div class="row">
                <h3 class="meta col-md-4 col-xs-6">Date of Birth <span class="label label-default">{{ student.DateofBirth | date }}</span></h3>
                <h3 class="meta col-md-4 col-xs-6">State <span class="label label-default">{{ student.State }}</span></h3>
                <h3 class="meta col-md-4 col-xs-6">L.Govt <span class="label label-default">{{ student.lga }}</span></h3>
                <h3 class="meta col-md-4 col-xs-6">Year Enrolled <span class="label label-default">{{ student.YearEnrolled }}</span></h3>
                <h3 class="meta col-md-4 col-xs-6">Class <span class="label label-default">{{ student.EducationalLevel }}</span></h3>
                <h3 class="meta col-md-4 col-xs-6">Status <span class="label label-danger">{{ student.Status }}</span></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

instead of writing all that code out , i want to replace it with a directive like

```
<students></students>
```

here is my contoller for that particular module

```
angular.module('studentList',[]);
/*
app.service('studentListService',['$http',function($http){
    return $http.get('http://localhost/database2/php/students.php')
        .success(function(data){
            return data;
        })
        .error(function(err){
            return err;
        });
}])
*/
app.controller('studentsController', ['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.title = 'Student List';
    $scope.students = [
        {
            "id":"2015552117",
            "FirstName":"Alexia",
            "MiddleName":"Gino",
            "LastName":"Bella",
            "Gender":"Male",
            "DateofBirth":"2015-04-30",
            "State":"Abuja",
            "YearEnrolled":"0000",
            "EducationalLevel":"JS 2",
            "lga":"Tema",
            "Status":"Oweing"
        },
        {
            "id":"2015551756",
            "FirstName":"Anthiny",
            "MiddleName":"akp",
            "LastName":"tony",
            "Gender":"male",
            "DateofBirth":"2015-04-28",
            "State":"Ekiti",
            "YearEnrolled":"0000",
            "EducationalLevel":"SS 3",
            "lga":"itu",
            "Status":"Oweing"
        },
        {
            "id":"2015551627",
            "FirstName":"Anthony",
            "MiddleName":"Atang",
            "LastName":"Akpan",
            "Gender":"male",
            "DateofBirth":"2015-01-10",
            "State":"Akwa Ibom",
            "YearEnrolled":"0000",
            "EducationalLevel":"SS 2",
            "lga":"jega",
            "Status":"Graduated"
        }
    ];
}]);

app.directive('students', function(){
    console.log("Returning Student Array");
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            info: '='
        },
        templateUrl:'/student.html'
    };
});
```

im still pretty new to Angular so some help will be appreciated i didnt ask the question in the right way last time so i have to track back

Comment: what is the `info` object that you are passing in to the scope there?

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @Claies , it was a typo , i changed it back to "student.FirstName"

Comment: @DavidGrinberg , how do it replace the initial snippet of code with a directive , i cant seem to get it to work. when i replace it with the <students></students> tags it shows up blank

Comment: @AnthonyAkpan Please update your question to reflect this. Most probably `'student.html'` isnt being loaded properly. Check the console for error messages.

Comment: you may have changed it in the HTML, but you still have `info: '='` in your directive.

Comment: @Claies , removing the scope dosent change the outcome , im actually still confused as to when to use a scope in a directive and when not to. Care to elaborate?

Comment: it's blank because the first line is an `ng-repeat` which doesn't have any data in it.

Comment: @Claies , manually pasting in that html (the first snippet) in place of the <student> element actually works. However the element is a child of  <div ng-repeat="student in students" class="student">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a basic plunker for your code, and a variation on the code.

First, a copy that works correctly without using a scope on the directive:

http://plnkr.co/edit/NlkEATHYm9DJwpscHfLu?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="studentList">
  <div ng-controller="studentsController">
    <Students></Students>
    </div>
</body>

app.directive('students', function(){
    console.log("Returning Student Array");
    return {
        restrict: 'E',

        templateUrl:'student.html'
    };
});
```

Secondly, an example using a scope.  The main benefit to using a scope is that you can have multiple copies of your directive on the same page, and each copy can have it's own set of data.

http://plnkr.co/edit/y3fOotXybQeq5PY4JVlD?p=preview

```
<body ng-app="studentList">
  <div ng-controller="studentsController">
    <Students students=students></Students>
  </div>
</body>

app.directive('students', function(){
    console.log("Returning Student Array");
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          students: '='
        },
        templateUrl:'student.html'
    };
});
```

Comment: thanks ALOT! will look aat your code and will be good. one last question , in what situation should scopes be used in a  directive and when is it no needed? another thing i tried to share my plunk cant seem to find the url for that

Comment: I tried to explain a bit in the answer about the scope... essentially you should try to use a scope on a directive whenever the directive is going to be re-used by others, or used multiple times on the same page.  The angular documentation explains it very well... https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive.  As to sharing the plunker, you have to have a github account to save and share them.